# How to type an angular component['s selector] to a variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, selector, typescript-typings

I'm building a custom multi drag-and-drop functionality into an angular app, and in one of the services, I iterate through an array of host components (`<app-cell>`).

As I iterate through the array of 's is there a way to assign a "custom typing" to my iterative variable?  In other words, how can I confine tile's type to app-tile?

This isn't the exact code, but more or less, it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

```
let selectedTiles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('app-tile'));

selectedTiles.map((tile: **WHAT GOES HERE?**) => {
  // do something with tile
}
```

I've used models before for 'custom typing' simple objects with particular keys, but I don't know what to do with trying to narrow assignment to my own angular component.

From my own googling, TemplateRef or directives seem to be on the right path, but my understanding of either is hazy and could use some direction as to what typing I could use!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled across the answer while reading angular documents.  Unfortunately, custom typing isn't possible:

> When [Generic DOM APIs, such as document.createElement() or document.querySelector() are] called with unknown elements, such as a custom element name (popup-element in our example), the methods will return a generic type, such as HTMLElement, since TypeScript can't infer the correct type of the returned element.

[Link here](https://angular.io/guide/elements#typings-for-custom-elements)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what type “**selectedTiles**” is.
Its type will be something like `Array<T>`, suppose here it is some type `{ id: number, dataset: Array<string> }`.
Since you are mapping over the selectedTile array, each element (here "**tile**") will of type `T`.

To be more specific, can you please share which service you are using. Also, if possible can you share the code link

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  The function itself isn't really relevant.  tile is <app-tile>, as queried from document.querySelector

Comment: I cleaned up the code to minimize my true goal here! 

`let selectedTiles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('app-tile'));

selectedTiles.map((tile: **WHAT GOES HERE?**) => {
  // do something with tile
}`

Comment: Okay, since `<app-tile>` is a component, the type will be of component itself, **AppTile**, you can type it to the component class

Comment: And yep, the typing currently is T or any I think, but I want to confine tile to app-tile, so I don't accidentally pass in a different dom element.

Comment: Just a suggestion though, its not a good practice to select using the document.querySelectorAll in Angular, there is ViewChildren decorator. You can use it like   `@ViewChildren(AppTileComponent) appTiles: QueryList<AppTileComponent>;`

Comment: Ahh okay gotcha, I just tried that, but VSC throws a red error squiggle because 'Cannot find name "AppTile"'.  I think this is because I'm in a service file.

Comment: Ah yes thanks.  Yep, it pains me a little, because I know it's bad practice.  But the whole setup is a bit confusing, because the user manually clicks on multiple tiles, which are applied a class.  So I need to grab all only a specific subset of tiles.  And do so from not just the parent component, but a service file.

Comment: one way is to import the `AppTileComponent` in your service and use it directly to type it **OR** you can create an interface like `ITile` and make your `AppTileComponent` implements it. Also, use this interface to type it in service

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work.  Because the AppTileComponent or rather, TileComponent, is the actual component class, whereas tile, from the query selector is the actual DOM element.  And the two don't match.

Comment: Well, if you can help me with the code link, we can have a look at specific solution.

Comment: I found the answer when I stumbled across a portion of the angular docs, but thanks!